# About using the mvccontrib grid in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: mvccontrib

I have a data source as a DataTable [this will have a varying columns]. I want to bind this datatable to the mvc contrib's Grid in asp.net MVC2. I donot have a fixed model that can explain my data.

Is it possible to do this in MVC Contrib Grid?.

[Details are available here also in CodePlex](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7160)

Comment: is there any way to get the output of the grid by giving the dataTable.AsEnumerable() as an IEnumerable Datasource and getting the StringWriter output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Reply from Jeremy, regarding use of MVCContrib Grid in ASP.NET MVC 2.0

> It is only designed to work with strongly-typed objects with a fixed
>   number of columns - not dynamic objects and not datatables.

This post is closed